Let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous and bijective. Prove/disprove that $f$ preserves interior points: $f(S^\circ) \subset f(S)^\circ$ for all $S\subset X$.
I don't know how to start. Let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous and bijective. Prove or disprove that $f$ preserves interior points, that is $f(S^\circ) \subset f(S)^\circ$ for all $S\subset X$.
Note: $A^\circ$ represents the set of interior points of $A$.
Can anyone teach me how to do?
